# LAUNCHER activity is not loaded for the first time in android

Tags: android

### I Have the Code in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.login.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main.screen.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

---

**What is happening:**

- The i load the app for the first time (Ex: Install it from
  androidStudio) 'MainActivity' is loaded but once i close and launch
  again `LoginActivity` is launched everytime
- This happens for the first time
- `MainActivity` launching happening for the first time
- Its should always load 'LoginActivity' right since my launcher is
  'LoginActivity' why is `LoginActivity` loaded just for first time. Is
  there any setting i need to check

Answer (score 1):

You have used

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in your main activity. According to docs -

if an existing instance of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task, but not at the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.

So that's why MainActivity is loading.

You should remove

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to get desired results.

For more information on launch modes refer docs - 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element